# SQL query that is able to count days based on event queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I posted this [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303434/sql-query-that-is-able-to-count-days-based-on-event-queries) but also decided to post here.

I have a table with the following data:

```
id    date_changed                  color_start         color_end
-------------------------------------------------------------------

1     2020-05-27 16:33:52.000       green                yellow
1     2020-06-11 20:12:18.000       yellow               red
1     2020-06-11 20:20:58.000       red                  green
2     2021-03-03 14:31:44.000       yellow               red
2     2020-08-06 14:59:21.000       green                yellow              
3     2021-04-28 12:36:45.000       green                red
...
```

Fore example, item with id #2 went from green to yellow on 2020-08-06 14:59:21 and then on 2021-03-03 14:31:44 it went from yellow to read. I need to count how many items were in green, yellow, red state between two time ranges.

I tried the following query by doing some research to basically list events or everyday for the past year, but it is not really what I want.

```
SELECT d.date, items.id,
count(CASE WHEN items.color_end = 'yellow' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as yellow_count,
count(CASE WHEN items.color_end = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as green_count,
count(CASE WHEN items.color_end = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as red_count,
count(CASE WHEN items.color_end = 'yellow' THEN 1 ELSE null end) + 
count(CASE WHEN items.color_end = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE null END) + 
count(CASE WHEN items.color_end = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as total_count
FROM (SELECT to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date 
      FROM generate_series(0, 365, 1) AS offs
     ) d LEFT OUTER JOIN
     events items
     ON d.date = to_char(date_trunc('day', item.date_changed), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY d.date, items.id;
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you add your desired output as well.

Answer (score 0):

*" I need to count how many items were in green, yellow, red state between two time ranges"*

First we calculate the time range associated to every color and every id.

```
SELECT id, color_start AS color
     , tsrange
         ( CASE 
             WHEN first_value(color_end) OVER w IS DISTINCT FROM color_start
             THEN NULL :: timestamp without time zone
             ELSE first_value(date_changed) OVER w
           END
         , CASE 
             WHEN last_value(color_start) OVER w  IS DISTINCT FROM color_end
             THEN NULL :: timestamp without time zone
             ELSE date_changed
           END
         ) AS range
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM your_table
       UNION ALL
       ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
                id, date_changed, color_end, NULL
           FROM your_table
          ORDER BY id, date_changed DESC
       )
     ) AS t
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_changed ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING)
```

Result is :

```
id  color   range
1   green   (,"2020-05-27 16:33:52")
1   yellow  ["2020-05-27 16:33:52","2020-06-11 20:12:18")
1   red     ["2020-06-11 20:12:18","2020-06-11 20:20:58")
1   green   ["2020-06-11 20:20:58",)
2   green   (,"2020-08-06 14:59:21")
2   yellow  ["2020-08-06 14:59:21","2021-03-03 14:31:44")
2   red     ["2021-03-03 14:31:44",)
3   green   (,"2021-04-28 12:36:45")
3   red     ["2021-04-28 12:36:45",)
```

Then, assuming that we want the number of colors per ids in the time range `tsrange('2020-06-01','2021-01-01')` the query is :

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT id, color_start AS color
     , tsrange
         ( CASE 
             WHEN first_value(color_end) OVER w IS DISTINCT FROM color_start
             THEN NULL :: timestamp without time zone
             ELSE first_value(date_changed) OVER w
           END
         , CASE 
             WHEN last_value(color_start) OVER w  IS DISTINCT FROM color_end
             THEN NULL :: timestamp without time zone
             ELSE date_changed
           END
         ) AS range
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM your_table
       UNION ALL
       ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
                id, date_changed, color_end, NULL
           FROM your_table
          ORDER BY id, date_changed DESC
       )
     ) AS t
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_changed ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING)
)
SELECT id, count(*)
  FROM list
 WHERE range && tsrange('2020-06-01','2021-01-01')
 GROUP BY id
```

and the result is :

```
id  count
1   3
2   2
3   1
```

the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6c48307a4e9b301778d3210918cecd73)